# how to update data from meteor in meteor using template helper which contain iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, textbox, updates

i just explored the meteor.js and have some experiment.. i want to update data using textbox.. but the textbox is generated from template helper iteration..

so, the scenario is just like we input data first and then retrive it and we can edit our data.. so when we edit

the problem is i cannot get a value from the textbox.. its always "undefined".. here is my html code :

```
<body>
    <form class="InsertTEST">
        <input type="text" name="att1" placeholder="fill the att1"/>
        <input type="text" name="att2" placeholder="fill the att3"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <table>
        {{#each a}}
            {{> test}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</body>

<template name="test">
    <tr class="testRow">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="toogle-check"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="att4" value="{{att1}}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="att5" value="{{att2}}"/></td>
        <td><a href="#">{{att3}}</a></td>
        <td><button class="UpdateTEST">Update</button></td>
        <td><button class="DeleteTEST">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

and here my js code :

```
TEST = new Mongo.Collection('TEST');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.body.helpers({
        a: function() {
            return TEST.find();
        }
    });

    Template.body.events({
        'submit .InsertTEST' : function(event){

            var _att1 = event.target.att1.value;
            var _att3 = new Date();
            var _att2 = Number(event.target.att2.value) + 10;

            Meteor.call('InsertTEST', _att1, _att2, _att3);

            event.target.att1.value = "";
            event.target.att2.value = "";


            return false;
        }


    });

    Template.test.events({

        'click .UpdateTEST' : function(e,t) {
            var _att4 = $('#att4').val();
            alert(_att4);


            /*
            var query = {
                att1 : _att4,
                att2 : _att5
            };
            */
            TEST.update(this._id, {$set:query});
            return false;
        }

    });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'InsertTEST' : function(_att1, _att2, _att3) {

            TEST.insert({
                att1:_att1, att2:_att2
            });

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't name your helper "a", you need to get a proper name. Second, you are not supposed to use a `body` tag in the meteor. It is generated by the server, and your templates are loaded into it.

Let's say your parent template is called `MainTemplate`

Your helper could look like that:

```
Template.MainTemplate.helpers({
    "item":function(){
       return TEST.find();
     }
});
```

and you just replace your spacebars iteration with this:

```
    {{#each item}}
        {{> test}}
    {{/each}}
```

A good practice when you get something undefined is to try to log its parent (`console.log(this);` in your `Template.test.rendered` function). It allows you to find the right way to invoke your object (i.e. where it is in your template).

Comment: Hi Billybobbonnet, thanks for your answer.. i'll take your advice about the proper name and the tag body :D.. About the render stuff i will try it first.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why? You have duplicated ids in your HTML. You render input with id *att4* and *att5* multiple times. ID should be unique in your HTML document. You should replace static IDs with dynamic IDs used inside forEach loop in your *test* template:

```
<td><input type="text" id="{{_id}}4" value="{{att1}}"/></td>
<td><input type="text" id="{{_id}}5" value="{{att2}}"/></td>
```

`{{_id}}` will insert current document id as an ID for HTML element.

You can then access a value of input with `$('#' + this._id + numberOfInput).val()` inside your UpdateTest event:

```
Template.test.events({

    'click .UpdateTEST' : function(e,t) {
        var _att4 = $('#' + this._id + 4).val();
        var _att5 = $('#' + this._id + 5).val();
        alert('_att4 = ' + _att4 + ', _att5 = ' + _att5);
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi Tomas Hromnik, thanks for your help.. i have tried it but it still return undefined value..

Comment: Oh sorry, there was a small mistake in my code, try it now. It should work ;-)

Comment: Hi Tomas, thx for your help its working now :D.. Btw about the syntax is it called jquery or the javascript? Sorry for my stupid question.. Im still newbie to programming world